# Desktop remote control software without screen synchronising

Tags: remote-desktop, remote, remote-control

I have a computer at home running Windows 10 Education version and I would like to remote control it from my office. The computer itself is connected to a screen, but when I am gone, I simply turn the screen off. However, since I live with flatmates, I do not want anybody else see what I am doing on the computer, nor I would like them to be able to see what I am doing.

Therefore, I would like to be able to remote control it, without the screen on my home computer moving or actually doing anything. Is there something in Windows 10 Education I can use to achieve this feature? Or another program?

I know I can use LogMeIn or Teamviewer, but these solutions do synchronise my actions, so if my flatmates turn on the screen, they would be able to see it.

Perhaps I should clarify my question. There is **only one** screen, which is the screen at home. I would like to access my home computer in my office. So teamviewer replicates the movements I make on my office computer on my **home screen**. I do not want to show anything on the PC screen at home, I would just like to the desktop on my "remote access tool" and not on the main screen.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just change the display options to extend rather than duplicate, this was you can just keep everything on your main pc screen, and if your housemates do turn on the screen that is attached all they will see is the desktop

like this

https://res.cloudinary.com/dlkdmqcop/image/upload/v1552399652/SCREEN_ncn7t3.png

regards